# Contracting Map

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

I'm reading the article "The dynamics of 2-generator subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ - Brooks and Matelski" and I'm in trouble with the following statment:

"Let $f(z) = z^2 +c$ and $p \in \mathbb{C}$, $|p|<1/2$  a stable periodic point of period $n$, i.e. $\left|\frac{d}{dz}f^n (p)\right|<1$. Expanding $f^n(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{2^n}{a_i(z-p)^{i}}$ as a Taylor series about $p$, we have

\begin{equation}
|f^n(z) - p| = |z-p| \left|\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}{a_i(z-p)^{i-1}}\right| \leq |z-p| .\max{\{|a_i|\}}.\max{\{1, |z-p|^{2^n -1}\}}.
\end{equation} 
Setting $K\leq \frac{1-\left|\frac{d}{dz}f^n (p)\right|}{(2^n -1)\max{\{|a_i|\}}}$, we see that on the disk $|z-p| < \min{\{1,K\}}$, $f^n$ is a contracting map."

I have been working in it but I couldn't proof that. Can anyone help me? Maybe there is something missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I have a proof. I will use the Schwarz Lemma: Let $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be a holomorphic map, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk centered in $0$, such that $f(0) =0$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ on $\mathbb{D}$. Then $|f(z)|\leq |z| \; \forall z \in \mathbb{D}$ and $|\frac{d}{dz}f(0)|\leq 1$.

Let define $h(w) := f^n(w+p) -p$. According with the above inequality $h$ satisfy the conditions to apply Schwarz Lemma. Then $$|h(w)|\leq |w| \Rightarrow |f^n(z) -
 p| \leq |z-p|,$$
and $f^n$ is a contract map. Do you think that this is a solution?

Comment: How can you prove $f^n$ is contract, i.e. $|f^n(z)-f^n(w)| \le |z-w|$ from that ?

Comment: After a night of sleep I can see that it would not help in the proof of it.

Comment: I can prove $f$ is contracting on a smaller disk (a smaller $K$). But I read the article and I found confusing because the authors insisted that $f$ is contracting in the disk with a given $K$...

Comment: How did you manage to demonstrate that?